# How can I get text from span(s) in dirs which are located in table?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have just only recently started using selenium and I can't get it to work properly.

I need to get a text from (s) which are inside dives which are inside a table.

Like this:

```
<td class="some-class">
"""many divs above"""
  <div class="props">
    <span>text</span>
    <span class="mr2">text</span>
  </div>
"""/many divs above"""
</td>
```

So, I need to get 'text(s)' from spans, but also there are many td s like this one and inside divs, classes repeat.

Moreover, how can I get it as a list?

I have tried this:

```
el = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('dir.props > span')
print(el)
for i in el:
    dict_of_orders.append(i.text)
print(dict_of_orders)
```

However, it returns only empty lists.
Any advice?:)

Thanks ahead for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello for future someone like me. My problem was solved by adding the delay.
Check it, maybe a site that you're trying to parse is slow.
`time.sleep(5)` was the answer.

```
el =browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='props']/span")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your CSS selector. It should be `div` instead of `dir`:

```
el = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.props > span')
```

I don't know if that will fix your problem, but you'll have to fix that.

Another thing I would try is, instead of `text`, use the `innerText` attribute, like this:

```
    dict_of_orders.append(i.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

Comment: Yeah, no it didn't fix. Thanks, nonetheless!

Comment: is your element inside of a frame or iframe?

Comment: No, just in many divs, inside a table, which inside more divs

Comment: Another thing I would try is, instead of text, use the innerText attribute. See my edited answer for that.

Comment: No, I can't even get just a simple list or whatever will be a result from print(el) So, even if innerText will help, it is useless now as I convert nothing to text.

Comment: I think, in order to properly diagnose this, I'd need the full HTML of or a link to the page you are testing.  I can't tell from the info you provided why the selector isn't working.

Comment: Sure thing, though this site is for sellers in Russia. I can only attach txt file for this.